# How do I do 2's compliment in MIPS?

Tags: mips

How do I do 2's compliment in MIPS? I need to print the decimal, binary, and hex with 2's compliment. This is what I have so far:

```
.data
    int: .word 0
    prompt: .asciiz "Please enter a 16 - bit integer: "
    msgDec: .asciiz "\nYour number as a decimal: " 
    msgBin: .asciiz "\nYour number in binary: "
    msgHex: .asciiz "\nYour number in Hexadecimal: " 
    
    twoComp: .asciiz "\nYour number in decimal with 2's comp: " 
    twoCompBin: .asciiz "\nYour number in binary with 2's comp: " 
    twoCompHex: .asciiz "/n Your number in Hex with 2's comp is: "
    
.text
    # Display first prompt
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt
    syscall
    #user input
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    #print as decimal
    move $t0, $v0
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, msgDec
    syscall
    li $v0, 1 
    move $a0, $t0
    syscall
    
    #print as Binary 
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, msgBin
    syscall
        move $a0, $t0
    li $v0,35
    syscall
    move $t1, $a0 #move binary into $t1
    
    #print as hex
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, msgHex
    syscall
    move $a0, $t0
    li $v0,34
    syscall
    move $t2, $a0 #move hex into $t2
    
    #2s compliment
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, twoComp
    syscall
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! OK, so where are you stuck specifically? How does your current code differ from the expected output? What is the expected output exactly? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Well I was finally able to have the user input a integer and print them as decimal, hex, and in binary. I just need a good idea of how to get the hex and binary to print with 2s compliment.

Comment: If you need to print signed numbers, if the number is >= 0, just print it as  you would an unsigned number.  Otherwise it is negative so print a `-` sign, negate the number 
(so it is now positive) and print that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.